# How can I use $scope in $on event handler

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularjs-scope

I am using Angular and Firebase. I want to  get values from  function `Datasnapshot` to  `$scope.getData`, but why I can't? Tell me please. Thanks.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {   
    var firebaseUrl ="https://angular-af216.firebaseio.com";
    var commentRef = new Firebase(firebaseUrl).child('User');

    commentRef.on('value', function(Datasnapshot) {
        var comments = Datasnapshot.val();
        // var data = Datasnapshot.child('User').val();
        console.log(comments);
        console.log("Newline");
        $scope.getData = comments;
        console.log(getData);
    });             
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject `$scope` in the function

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function ($scope) {   
        var firebaseUrl ="https://angular-af216.firebaseio.com";
        var commentRef = new Firebase(firebaseUrl).child('User');

        commentRef.on('value', function(Datasnapshot) {
        var comments = Datasnapshot.val();
        // var data = Datasnapshot.child('User').val();
        console.log(comments);
        console.log("Newline");
        $scope.getData = comments;
        console.log($scope.getData);
        });

      });
```

Comment: Because you need to access getData via `$scope.getData` in the `console.log`, but you haven't do that

Comment: Yes sir, but i inject $scope in the function  like you but it's same

Comment: Not only inject but also add `console.log($scope.getData);` instead of `console.log(getData);`

Comment: Oh thank you, but why i can't ues $scope.getData in view